Porque al leer el valor del handle es 0
Tengo problemas a la hora de leer un float almacenado en GPU utilizando CUDA, en el proceso A almaceno un float en GPU el cual le asigno un handle que luego comparto por shared memory, en el proceso B leo la memoria para obtener el handle y pasarlo de device a host pero el valor que me devuelve es 0, no se ha compartido el handle por shared memory o me falta algo por añadir?
ProcesoA.cu
float hostInt = 123.0;
float* devicePtr = nullptr;

checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&devicePtr, sizeof(float)));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(devicePtr, &hostInt, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
cudaIpcMemHandle_t handle;
cudaIpcGetMemHandle(&handle, devicePtr);

HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMappingW(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE,
    0,
    sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t),
    L"IpcHandle");
cudaIpcMemHandle_t* mapData = (cudaIpcMemHandle_t*)MapViewOfFile(
    hMapFile,
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    0,
    0,
    sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t));

*mapData = handle;

std::cin.get();

ProcesoB.cu
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMappingW(
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    FALSE,
    L"IpcHandle");
cudaIpcMemHandle_t* mapData = (cudaIpcMemHandle_t*)MapViewOfFile(
    hMapFile,
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    0,
    0,
    sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t));

cudaIpcMemHandle_t handle = *mapData;

float* ptr;
checkCudaErrors(cudaIpcOpenMemHandle((void**)&ptr, handle, cudaIpcMemLazyEnablePeerAccess));
checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

float *hostValue = nullptr;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&hostValue, ptr, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
std::cout << "Value: " << hostValue << std::endl;

std::cin.get();


¿ Como estás lanzando los procesos A y B ? Entiendo que en 2 consolas distintas, ¿ verdad ? Es decir, que A no termina hasta que B lo hace ¿ correcto ?

@Trauma si, son dos consolas distintas que ejecuto a la vez, el proceso A almacena un float en memoria GPU mientras que el B tiene un sleep_for de 2 segundos para que termine el A y después lo lea.

Me he expresado mal, para que termine no, para que acabe de guardar el float en memoria GPU y después se quede en espera hasta que B lo lea

Te diría que hicieras una prueba sin usar CUDA, intentando pasar un valor cualquiera. Para identificar si el problema viene de CUDA o de la memoria compartida.
